# Getting the size of a struct value

Tags: c

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
  char *b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char c[4] = { 'c', 'a', 't', '\0' };
  struct A a;
  a.b = c;
  printf("%s\n", a.b); // cat
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof c); // 4
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof a.b); // 8 ???
}
```

Why does `sizeof a.b` returns 8 and not 4? If I understood correctly, `a.b` returns the value that was assigned to it, which is `c`. But shouldn't it return the size of `c` (which is 4) then?

Comment: b is a pointer, not an array, you should use `strlen` in this case

Comment: it prints `sizeof(char *)`. i think your system is 64-bit.

Comment: Why aren't there parenthesis around the `sizeof` argument ?

Comment: @chmike: because they are not needed. Think of `sizeof` as an operator that looks typographically like a word.

Comment: @chmike it's supported. to variable, parens are not necessary.

Comment: @chmike sizeof() is a operator not a function so OP is good in that way

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array but I don't really like the answers there...

Comment: Thanks. never used it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `sizeof()` on two different types.

- `sizeof(a.b)` is `sizeof(char *)`, which is 8 on your platform.
- `sizeof(c)` is `sizeof(char[4])`, which is 4.

We can have pointers point to arrays via array decaying, which you can read about in this other answer: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof()` operator gives the number of  bytes allocated to the object and in your case the object is a pointer whose size looks like is 8 bytes on your system.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `sizeof(a.b)` is not size of `c`. It doesn't give size of what it is pointing to, rather it is size of the pointer.

Take an example of char:

- size of `char a` is 1
- and `char *b` is 4. (on 64 bit)

So it is size of the pointer not what it points to. *Please note these sizes are platform dependent.*

Although don't get confused by `int`. An `int` and `int *` are of same size on some platforms.

Comment: Sizeof is platform dependent. Please read  the question and the other answers check your `sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(int *)`

Comment: @JJao that is what i mentioned. My point is not about what exactly the size is, point is size of a pointer is not size of pointer object not what it points to. I would suggest you read my answer please.

Comment: Sorry to insist: Your basic reasoning is correct but some "facts" are not: from the question we can deduce that in this platform size of (char * ) is 8. In the same direction it is possible that size of int may be different form `sizeof (int*)`

Answer (score 1):

> If I understood correctly, a.b returns the value that was assigned to it,

Not exactly.  `a.b` is what's called an *lvalue*. This means that it *designates* a memory location. However it does not read that memory location yet; that will only happen if we use `a.b` within a larger context that expects the memory location to be read.

For example:

```
a.b = something;    // does not read a.b
something = a.b;    // does read a.b
```

The case of `sizeof` is one context where it does not read the memory location. In fact it tells you how many bytes comprise that memory location; it doesn't tell you anything about what is stored there (let alone about some other memory location that might be pointed to by what is stored there, if it is a pointer).

The output is telling you that your system uses `8` bytes to store a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

sizeof() returns the number of bytes of a variable. 
In this case sizeof ( char * ) returns 8 bytes which is the number of bytes that compose a pointer.